# Convert Presto row into column

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I have a presto table as such:

| column_1 | column_2 | column_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 4 |

I'd like the outcome to be:

| column | values |
| --- | --- |
| column_1 | 2 |
| column_2 | 1 |
| column_3 | 4 |

Should a pivot be used in this instance?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Presto/Trino does not provide "dynamic" unpivoting capabilities so you can turn your data into arrays and use `unnest`:

```sql
-- sample data
with dataset(column_1, column_2, column_3) as(
    values (12, 11, 14),
           (22, 21, 24)
)
-- query
select column, "values"
from (select array['column_1', 'column_2', 'column_3'] key,
        array[column_1, column_2, column_3] val
    from dataset),
unnest(key, val) as t(column, "values");
```

Output:

| column | values |
| --- | --- |
| column_1 | 12 |
| column_2 | 11 |
| column_3 | 14 |
| column_1 | 22 |
| column_2 | 21 |
| column_3 | 24 |